# My old PC died, do I need to reset/delete my SSH?

Tags: github

I am coding beginniner. My SSD drive died on my labtop and I bought a new one for it. Now that I am re-installing everything, I am wondering if I need to reset or delete my SSH for my github. Should I be making a new SSH? Please explain what my options are (in a new beginner terms). Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So you don´t have a backup of your SSH Key I guess? In this case I would just create a new one. You can follow the instructions from GitHub here, they explain the whole process pretty well. You can just add a new one!:) https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

For the future I recommend, always keep a copy (backup) at a safe place of your PGP, SSH Keys. :)